# Disable Warning Dialog if Bluetooth is powered off iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, bluetooth, ios7

My ios application uses bluetooth to connect to an accessory. If Bluetooth is not enabled, a popup appears asking me to activate.

[image: Bluetooth Popup]

I noticed that popup appears every time I run the application.

My question is whether it is possible to display the popup once, ie only after the first launch ([fitbit app do that](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fitbit-activity-calorie-tracker/id462638897?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4). I also want to know if it is possible to change the language of the popup.

My application is for iOS7 and iOS6

If we can't change the langage, is there a way to disable this popup then i will develop my own view (popup) with localized system ?

Thanks you a lot !

Comment: The langugage of that dialog is the system language and I don't think you can change it.

Comment: Thank your for your comment. My iphone is in French and the popup is displayed in English.

Comment: Is your app English, It might just look at the language that you app is set to. I've noticed English dialogs in my Dutch app because my iPhone is set to english.

Comment: I don't think that is related to the language of the application because the popup that asks me to authorize the location is in French. Strange. Maybe we cannot show the popup in other langages. But if i find the way to desactivate this popup, then i will develop my own popup with localized system

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the following response from an apple developer  :
In iOS7, the `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` option lets you disable this alert.

If you have a `CBCentralManager`, then when you initialise it, you can use the method `-[CBCentralManager initWithDelegate:queue:options]`

### Example:

In my .h file, I have a `CBCentralManager * manager`.

In my .m file:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @NO};
    
_manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:options];
    
[_manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
```

With this code, the warning no longer appears. I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, I have used it with iOS 9 and 8.4 but its still shows popup.

Comment: Still works with Swift 5: `, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: false]`

Answer (score 3):

If you are connecting to accessory devices, you might also be using the `CBPeripheralManager` instead of the `CBCentralManager`. Tuck me some time to figure this out, because I was using a sdk and couldn't tell what it actually did. But in this case you have to suppress the alert on the peripheral manager. Once the flag is set it will be valid for all other instances of the `CBCentralManager` or the `CBPeripheralManager` respectively. Im my case, the only reason I instantiated the `CBPeripheralManager` at all was to set the flag.

```
@property CBPeripheralManager *pManager;

*peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:nil queue:nil options:@{CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:@NO}];
```

Note that you have to assign the instance to a property or it won't work.