# Stop Bluetooth Alert Pop on iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, core-bluetooth, clbeaconregion

When I open my app on iOS 10.3 devices I get Bluetooth Alert Pop each time. Our App supports Apple Watch as well. I don't get this notification on devices lower than iOS 10.3. I tried all questions related to this on stackoverflow yet nothing clicks for me.

Alert Message which am getting is -

> "Turn on Bluetooth to Allow App to Connect to Accessories"

is there a way to disable this alert?

```
I use CLLocationManager and WSI SDK.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is alert​ for permission as according to apple guidelines it will ask user to enable/disable.
Check this reference may it helps :

http://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296642/disable-warning-dialog-if-bluetooth-is-powered-off-ios&grqid=iAvkoO3E&hl=en-IN

http://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533269/ios-check-if-bluetooth-is-on-without-system-alert-popup-to-user&grqid=T_P53yLJ&hl=en-IN

Comment: Thanks for your time to help me. I tried and read all these already.