# Disable default alert when Bluetooth is Turned OFF in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, core-bluetooth, rfid

I have integrated [SerialIO RFID SDK](https://serialio.com/) and using [Bluetooth LE Plugin](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le) to check Bluetooth Status in my Xamarin.iOS app.

Each time when I launch the app, it keeps showing me the alert as soon as any of the code from above SDK or plugin is invoked. I don't want to show this alert. Instead, I want to notify user about this, in some other way.

> I found [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296642/disable-warning-dialog-if-bluetooth-is-powered-off-ios) to disable this alert, but Where and How to
>   write this in Xamarin, is my Question.

I searched a lot for Xamarin Specific solution and didn't find any.

I tried following in `AppDelegate.cs` but none of them worked. May be I am not sure how to write this.

```
// Way : 1
var cbCentralInitOptions = new CBCentralInitOptions();
cbCentralInitOptions.ShowPowerAlert = false;
var cbCentralManager = new CBCentralManager(this, null, cbCentralInitOptions);

// Way : 2
//NSDictionary options = new NSDictionary();
//options.SetValueForKey(NSNumber.FromNUInt(0), CBCentralManager.OptionShowPowerAlertKey);
//var cbCentralManager = new CBCentralManager(this, null, options);
```

Please help me to get this default alert suppressed. Thanks.

Comment: Are you developing Xamarin.ios or xamarin.forms? I saw the gay solved his problem  with [CBCentralManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager).  If you want to disable the alert, you should create and manage `CBCentralManager` yourself instead of using third-party plugin.

Comment: 1. Xamarin.iOS.   2. Even if I remove plugin and related code, but due to the SDK initialization, this alert pops up. I understand, SDK might have used CBCentralManager, however, it is not open-sourced.   Thanks for your answer. Let me know if my comment can help you identify something else.